# RoR Tutorial (2nd Ed.) 3.3.4 Can't get Rspec test to pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

New to Rails and going through this books tutorial. Been scratching my head on this one for nearly day now so I could use some help. Unable to get this test to pass from section 3.3.4 of the 2nd Edition book. (Ruby on Rails Tutorial) See failures and code below:

Failures:

```
  1) Static pages Home page should have the title 'Home'
     Failure/Error: page.should have_selector('title', :text => 'Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home')
     expected to find css "title" with text "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home" but there were no matches. Also found 
     "", which matched the selector but not all filters.
     # ./spec/features/static_pages_spec.rb:15:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Static pages Help page should have the title 'Help'
     Failure/Error: page.should have_selector('title', :text => "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Help")
     expected to find css "title" with text "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App 
     | Help" but there were no matches. Also found 
     "", which matched the selector but not all filters.
     # ./spec/features/static_pages_spec.rb:28:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) Static pages About page should have the title 'About Us'
     Failure/Error: page.should have_selector('title', :text => "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | About")
     expected to find css "title" with text "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App 
     | About" but there were no matches. Also found
     "", which matched the selector but not all filters.
     # ./spec/features/static_pages_spec.rb:41:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

static_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rails_helper'

  describe "Static pages" do

    describe "Home page" do

      it "should have the h1 'Sample App'" do
        visit '/static_pages/home'
        page.should have_selector('h1', :text => 'Sample App')
      end

      it "should have the title 'Home'" do
        visit '/static_pages/home'
        page.should have_selector('title', 
                    :text => 'Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home')
      end
    end

    describe "Help page" do

      it "should have the h1 'Help'" do
        visit '/static_pages/help'
        page.should have_selector('h1', :text => 'Help')
      end

      it "should have the title 'Help'" do
        visit '/static_pages/help'
        page.should have_selector('title', 
              :text => "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Help")
      end
    end

    describe "About page" do

      it "should have the h1 'About Us'" do
        visit '/static_pages/about'
        page.should have_selector('h1', :text => 'About Us')
      end

      it "should have the title 'About Us'" do
        visit '/static_pages/about'
        page.should have_selector('title', 
              :text => "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | About")
      end
    end
  end
```

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | <%= yield(:title) %></title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

static_pages_controller.rb

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def help
  end

  def about
  end
end
```

home.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, 'Home') %>
<h1>Sample App</h1>
<p>
    This is the home page for the
    <a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
    sample application.
</p>
```

help.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, 'Help') %>
<h1>Help</h1>
<p>
    Get help on the Ruby on Rails Tutorial at the
    <a href="http://railstutorial.org/help">Rails Tutorial help page</a>
    . To get help on this sample app, see the
    <a href="http://railstutorial.org/book">Rails Tutorial book</a>.
</p>
```

about.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, 'About Us') %>
<h1>About Us</h1>
<p>
    The <a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
    is a project to make a book and screencasts to teach web development
    with <a href="http://rubyonrails.org/">Ruby on Rails</a>. This
    is the sample application for the tutorial.
</p>
```

gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


gem 'minitest'

gem 'test-unit'
gem 'rails_12factor'
ruby '2.1.5'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do


  gem 'sqlite3'

  gem 'capybara'

  gem 'rspec-rails'

  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

group :development do
    # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
    gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
    gem 'pg'
end
```

If anyone can get me pointed in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated. I prefer to stick to solutions closest to the books methods but if I have to do something differently to get this to pass and proceed onwards then I'll take what I can get. Just please to don't suggest me doing anything crazy advanced that I clearly should be getting into yet if at all possible. Thanks. Simple is better here.

Comment: The book just states:
"The technique involves using Embedded Ruby in our views. Since the Home, Help, and About page titles have a variable component, we'll use a special Rails function called provide to set a different title on each page. @ RailsOuter

Comment: Yes sorry I realized that.

Comment: try expect(page).to have_selector('title', 
                    :text => 'Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home') instead of page.should have_selector('title', 
                    :text => 'Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home')

Comment: You should see 2 errors instead of 3 if this works

Comment: Just tried it, and still returns all with errors.

Comment: The crazy thing is when running 'rails s' and actually navigating to the pages, they DO actually have the correct titles. Im at such a loss :( Leads me to believe that the issue is in the actual test syntax?

Comment: Can you update your question with the title tag as it shows on the source page. If you use Chrome it's under View -> Developer -> View Source.

Comment: admittedly I'm not entirely sure what you are asking. I am using Firefox by the way. @Marius Pop

Comment: @Arc_X In Firefox in the menu bar go to Tools -> Web Developer -> Page Source there is a tag that looks like this: ``<title>some name</title>``. Can you copy that and put it in your question: That's what your first test is expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `RSpec` and `Capybara` matchers in your spec, but you don't have those gems installed.

Here is the Gemfile from the 2nd edition:

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.16'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

Looking at *your* `Gemfile`, it appears you're using a newer version of Rails. If you are following Michael's tutorial, you should use the *same* versions that he specifies. There is a newer edition of the tutorial available, suited for Rails 4 development. You can read it here for free:

https://www.railstutorial.org/book

Comment: My bad. I accidentally linked in the wrong gemfile. Should be updated to reflect the actual gemfile now. For the record I was able to get all previous testing up to this point to work fine. On that note though, I had figured the different rails version I could work through but if there is a free rails 4 version out there I might go to that instead.

Comment: You're also using newer versions of RSpec and Capybara, which have changed since the 2nd edition of the book. For someone new to Rails, my advice is to follow along with the newest edition, using the exact versions he specifies in his `Gemfile`; that way you're less likely to run into issues.